# Format Localized DateTime C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to format localized date into format. e.g yyyyMMdd OR ddMMyyyy OR MMddyyyy based on system date format. Below is what I have tried and it is working , but need efficient way to do same.

```
DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().Date.ToString().Replace("/","").Replace(":","").Replace(" ","").Replace("-","")
```

Comment: "but need efficient way to do same" - what are your exact performance criteria, and what do your benchmarks show at the moment? (If you don't have precise performance criteria, or you haven't measured the current performance, you don't *really* know whether you need to make your current code more efficient or not.)

Comment: Take a look at [custom date and time format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: why you don't try to change the local date format on PC instead and read it directly from there ? 
check this site for date format https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_) overload([read also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)):

```
DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

(why you think you need `ToLocalTime` here? `Now` always returns the local time)

> cant use .ToString("yyyyMMdd") because i need different result
> depending on what my system date format is. if system date time is
> dd-MM-yyyy i want ddMMyyyy, if its yyyy-MM-dd then expected result is
> yyyyMMdd

Then you either stick with your current approach or use something like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d").Replace(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.DateSeparator, "")
```

Comment: cant use .ToString("yyyyMMdd") because i need different result depending on what my system date format is. if system date time is dd-MM-yyyy i want ddMMyyyy, if its yyyy-MM-dd then expected result is yyyyMMdd